# How can I force Linq to SQL NOT to use the cache?

Tags: linq-to-sql

When I make the same query twice, the second time it does not return new rows form the database (I guess it just uses the cache).

This is a Windows Form application, where I create the dataContext when the application starts.

How can I force Linq to SQL not to use the cache?

Here is a sample function where I have the problem:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> NewOrders()
{
    return from order in dataContext.Orders
           where order.Status == 1
           select order; 
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The simplest way would be to use a new DataContext - given that most of what the context gives you is caching and identity management, it really sounds like you just want a new context. Why did you want to create just the one and then hold onto it?

By the way, for simple queries like yours it's more readable (IMO) to use "normal" C# with extension methods rather than query expressions:

```
public IEnumerable<Orders> NewOrders()
{
    return dataContext.Orders.Where(order => order.Status == 1);
}
```

EDIT: If you *never* want it to track changes, then set [ObjectTrackingEnabled](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.linq.datacontext.objecttrackingenabled.aspx) to false before you do anything. However, this will severely limit it's usefulness. You can't just flip the switch back and forward (having made queries between). Changing your design to avoid the singleton context would be much better, IMO.

Comment: It is at major refactoring for me to use another DataContext, because it is wrapped in a framework library.

Comment: Well, that's basically what you need to do. When faced with a bad design decision made earlier, I usually find it's *much* better to roll up your sleeves and fix it than to work around it, making it harder and harder to fix later.

Comment: Well... that is not an option.

Comment: I've just edited my answer with an alternative, but I still think it's almost certainly a mistake. LINQ to SQL was just not designed to be used the way you're using it.

Comment: sorry... that came out a little harsh. It just that the framwork is developed for web, an I have to make a litle WinForm admin program. If I have to refactor the entire library, I have days of work and days of testing. I just dog get why a query is cashed, without the option to force a requery.

Comment: Are you using a single DataContext all the way through your web application as well? I have no idea what the concurrency properties of DataContext are - imagine doing similar queries at the same time with the same context from different threads...

Comment: That is... it is stored in the HttpContext.Current.Items in case the request is swapped to another thread during a request.

Comment: Okay, that's not so worrying then :) Can't you hook into the same logic for your WinForms app? Give yourself some sort of "fake context" such that you'll get a new DataContext?

Answer (score 0):

It can matter HOW you add an object to the DataContext as to whether or not it will be included in future queries.

**Will NOT add the new InventoryTransaction to future in memory queries**

In this example I'm adding an object with an ID and then adding it to the context.

```
var transaction = new InventoryTransaction()
                 {
                     AdjustmentDate = currentTime,
                     QtyAdjustment = 5,
                     InventoryProductId = inventoryProductId
                 };

dbContext.InventoryTransactions.Add(transaction);
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Linq-to-SQL isn't clever enough to see this as needing to be added to the previously cached list of in memory items in `InventoryTransactions`.

**WILL add the new InventoryTransaction to future in memory queries**

```
var transaction = new InventoryTransaction()
                 {
                     AdjustmentDate = currentTime,
                     QtyAdjustment = 5
                 };

inventoryProduct.InventoryTransactions.Add(transaction);
dbContext.SubmitChanges();
```

Wherever possible use the collections in Linq-to-SQL when creating relationships and not the IDs.

In addition as Jon says, try to minimize the scope of a DataContext as much as possible.