# Disable LINQ to SQL Query Cache in C# .NET Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

We have a number of customer databases (all single tenant) and a number of APIs that access these databases.

The APIs are aware of the customer accessing the various endpoints by virtue of access tokens, and a DbContext is created for each request that comes in, to ensure we hit the correct database. The API is pretty busy so we've got DbContext's being created and disposed of all the time.

We use a PredicateBuilder to deal with query string parameters that are converted into SQL via LINQ and Entity Framework. Here is an example that is applied to our queryable as part of a query string parameter:

```
var predicate = PredicateBuilder.New<Property>(true);


if (query.OwnerIds != null && query.OwnerIds.Any())
{
    predicate = predicate.And(p => query.OwnerIds.Contains(p.PrimaryOwner) || query.OwnerIds.Contains(p.SecondaryOwner));
}

return predicate;
```

The predicate is then used in the `Where` condition when calling the DbContext eg

```
this.dbContext.Where(predicate).ToListAsync();
```

I am seeing a problem where the compiled query uses values from a previous web request, which results in the wrong data being returned. Take the following scenario:

Customer A makes a called to `/endpoint?ownerId=ABC`

This gets converted into SQL that looks something similar to

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM `data` AS `p`
WHERE (((`p`.`primaryOwner` = 'ABC') OR (`p`.`secondaryOwner` = 'ABC')))
```

Customer B makes a similar request, but with different parameters to `/endpoint?ownerIds=XYZ`

What I would expect here is that a query similar to the above would be built:

```
SELECT EXISTS (
SELECT 1
FROM `data` AS `p`
WHERE (((`p`.`primaryOwner` = 'XYZ') OR (`p`.`secondaryOwner` = 'XYZ')))
```

However the first query runs, as though the query string parameters have never changed.

I cannot find anything online that relates to this problem and am struggling to resolve it. Can anybody provide any pointers?

Comment: How do you inject the DbContext? How do you generate the `predicate` (i.e. what happens between `return predicate` and `.Where(predicate)`)? How would a freshly-built predicate contain values from an earlier request? Is there a caching layer in between, is stuff static, do you reuse your DbContext between requests?

Comment: The DbContext is registered as a transient class at runtime, so it should be a new instance for every request. The DbContext is provided via a factory class that is injected into the repository. I'm not convinced the predicate itself is the problem, it seems to be that when LINQ converts the query to SQL, it's using old values. Unfortunately I can't replicate the problem on demand it just keeps occurring on our production environment. Restarting the container fixes the issue, but only for a limited period.

Comment: _"The DbContext is provided via a factory class that is injected into the repository"_ - does that perhaps share things between requests and/or threads? It's just really hard for us to diagnose. Sure, the expression may be cached somewhere by EF, where a false positive cache hit may be caused by the way LINQKit's PredicateBuilder builds expressions, which I doubt TBH. You'll need to paint us a complete picture, see [mre].

Comment: Perhaps you can whip up a repro if you look at https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/main/src/EFCore/Query/ExpressionEqualityComparer.cs.

Comment: Thanks - appreciate the comment about a reproducible example, the problem is I can't reproduce it

Comment: Compiled Query? Do you mean EF Compiled query?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure - I mean the actual SQL that gets run against the database (LINQ to SQL presumably)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I force Linq to SQL NOT to use the cache?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/300402/how-can-i-force-linq-to-sql-not-to-use-the-cache)

Comment: Unfortunately not - Our DbContext is provided by way of a factory class which is registered with a transient lifetime so it should always be fresh for every request which is another reason why I can work out why i'm seeing the behaviour noted. It does seem related to volume of traffic in some ways as it's become more prevalent as the load on the API has increased. I've updated the repository methods to call AsNoTracking() to see if that solves the issue

Comment: What is the Factory class for creating the DbContext? Why not just inject DbContext directly? - additionally, how is the Factory class registered (singleton by any chance?)

Comment: @RobertPerry see comment above. the factory class is registered as transient. We have to use a factory class because the DbContext is different depending on the dataset we are connecting to (single tenant databases) so we have to switch out the connection string with each request for a different customer.